# How to show a div1 div2 div3 div4 div5 using html input button1 button2 button3 button4 button5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have 5 div tag and 5 html input button also, i want to select/show one div at a time using html input button click.

```
<script>
      $(function () {
          // Store our questions in a variable
          var $questions = $('.question');

          // Show the first question
          $questions.first().show();

          // When clicking the <button> in ny of the questions...
          $questions.find('input').on('click', function () {
              // ...store the currently visible question, then...
              var $visibleQuestion = $questions.filter(':visible');

              // ...if there's a next question....
              var $nextQuestion = $visibleQuestion.next('.question');
              console.log($nextQuestion);
              if ($nextQuestion.length === 1) {
                  // ...hide the visible question....
                  $visibleQuestion.hide();
                  // ..and show the next.
                  $nextQuestion.show();
              }
                  // If you want, you can check for quiz completition in this else section
              else {
                  // Quiz finished
                  alert('You finished the quiz!');
              }
          });
          // Optionally, change the text of the last question's button
          $questions.last().find('input').text('Finish Quiz');
      });
    </script>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                                        var x, y;
                                        var i = 0;
                                        var j = 0;
                                        for (x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
                                            for (y = 0; y < 5; y = y + 1) {
                                                document.write('<input id="button' + (i + 1) + '" class="btnClass" type="button"  value="' + (i + 1) + '" style="width:30px; height:25px;text-align:left;" />');

                                                i++;
                                                document.write('&nbsp &nbsp');
                                                if (i % 5 == 0) {
                                                    document.write('<br /> <br />');
                                                }
                                            }


                                        }
                                    </script>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question and include the relevant source code to your question and any attempt(s) that you have made so far. Thank you.

Comment: so did you tried anything? If yes add html+css(if any)+most important your effort what you tried. It's fine that it not worked.We will check and try to rectify it

Comment: I created 100 buttons but i don't know how to do action with div using these buttons

Comment: i'm trying to show something in each div using 100 button one by one, means i want to create a small examination system

Comment: You can post 2-3 of them (div with there corresponding button) along with your jQuery code what you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is here to help with code you wrote but SO is not here to write code for you.

Comment: plz take a look at above

Comment: All that code does is add to the confusion. What does it do? Does it work? If not, what doesn't work? How does it not work?

Comment: and using for loop i created 100 input buttons

Comment: ok then leave it , i will find or try somehing else to solve my query

Comment: Since you are abandoning your question, you should delete this altogether.

Comment: you don't need to write codes for me, just hint me what i do to select div1 using button1 and to select div2 using button2, then i will try to do same with all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 5 divs which are initially hidden and display  when clicked on the button.

```
$(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#btn2").click(function()
                {
                    $("#two").removeClass("hidden");
                });
            });
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#btn3").click(function()
                {
                    $("#three").removeClass("hidden");
                });
            });
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#btn4").click(function()
                {
                    $("#four").removeClass("hidden");
                });
            });
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#btn5").click(function()
                {
                    $("#five").removeClass("hidden");
                });
            });


 <body>
 <style type="text/css">
    .hidden
    {
        visibility:hidden;
    }
 </style>
                <button id="btn1">DIV 1</button>
                <button id="btn2">DIV 2</button>
                <button id="btn3">DIV 3</button>
                <button id="btn4">DIV 4</button>
                <button id="btn5">DIV 5</button>


        <div id='one' class="hidden">1 Lorem </div>
        <div id="two" class="hidden">2 lorem</div>
        <div id="three" class="hidden">3 lorem </div>
        <div id="four" class="hidden">4 lorem </div>
        <div id="five" class="hidden">5 lorem </div>
```

Comment: Thank You very much sir, i was also serching regarding this and i also find more to learn, thanks again

Comment: @AjitSingh you're welcome. You can close this thread by selecting my answer as the right answer.

Comment: i'm new here i don't know how to close it

Comment: Thanks you Aabhushan Gautam Sir for providing solution.